# Can multiplying a pair of almost-one values ever yield a result of 1.0?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have two floating point values, `a` and `b`.  I can guarantee they are values in the domain (0, 1).  Is there any circumstance where `a * b` could equal one?  I intend to calculate `1/(1 - a * b)`, and wish to avoid a divide by zero.

My instinct is that it cannot, because the result should be equal or smaller to `a` or `b`.  But instincts are a poor replacement for understanding the correct behavior.

I do not get to specify the rounding mode, so if there's a rounding mode where I could get into trouble, I want to know about it.

Edit: I did not specify whether the compiler was IEEE compliant or not because I cannot guarantee that the compiler/CPU running my software will indeed by IEEE compliant.

Comment: to be super clear, both values are in the domain 0<a,b<1? Not ≤?

Comment: Floating point numbers don't work like real numbers do in math. They have rounding errors. If a number is sufficiently close to `0` it can turn into `0`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux (a) that is not the question... it is about a number < 1 turning into 1 and (b) I don't think even what you're saying about 0 is true.  The floating-point standard includes certain guarantees against non-intuitive behavior, even taking into account rounding error.

Comment: @JoelFan The denominator is `1 - a * b`.  As `a` and `b` approach `1` it approaches `0`. OP wants to avoid division by zero, which is in the question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, ok but the 0 would have to be the result of a subtraction, not a multiplication.  I'm certain that the IEEE standard guarantees a - b > 0 where a > b

Comment: @JoelFan There *is* a subtraction: product is subtracted from 1.

Comment: @Aconcagua, that's exactly my point.  Once we know the product < 1, then the subtraction from 1 will never be 0, per the IEEE standard for subtraction.  Combining the guarantees for multiplication and subtraction, we can see that he will never divide by 0.

Comment: @JoelFan Seem to have misunderstood your latest comment... Still: Any reference for these guarantees?

Comment: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling) might help you detect a division by zero.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, you are correct.  In theory the 0 side isn't too important, I just wanted to explicitly exclude any pathologically large negative values which could complicated the story.  Obviously `0*b != 1`, so there's no issue there.  But I do have a strong guarantee that `a < 1` is true and `b < 1` is true.

Comment: @Aconcagua, have fun: https://irem.univ-reunion.fr/IMG/pdf/ieee-754-2008.pdf .  There is also the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: @CortAmmon I'd be interested why you would not assume IEEE 754 compliance.  I don't think there are any C++ implementations in general use that *don't* use that standard.  In any event, if you really insist that it may not follow the standard, then your question is unanswerable and should be closed.

Comment: @JoelFan This code may run on an embedded platform.  They are known as a whole for being... quirky...

Comment: @CortAmmon, in that case, we don't have enough information to answer your question, and it should be closed.  You may want to ask the manufacturer of the platform.  Alternatively write your code such that it behaves reasonably in case of divide-by-zero.

Comment: Re “But I do have a strong guarantee that `a < 1` is true and `b < 1` is true”: This is a bit worrisome given that floating-point arithmetic is in use. Is the guarantee based in analysis of the floating-point arithmetic used to compute `a` and `b`, not just in what they represent mathematically? I.e., are you sure no rounding errors in the calculations that produce `a` and `b` result in them rounding up to 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have two floating point values, `a` and `b`…

Since this says we have “values,” not “variables,” it admits a possibility that `1 - a*b` may evaluate to 1. When writing about software, people sometimes use names as placeholders for more complicated expressions. For example, one might have an expression `a` that is `sin(x)/x` and an expression `b` that is `1-y*y` and then ask about computing `1 - a*b` when the code is actually `1 - (sin(x)/x)*(1-y*y)`. This would be a problem because C++ allows extra precision to be used when evaluating floating-point expressions.

The most common instances of this is that the compiler uses `long double` arithmetic while computing expressions containing `double` operands or it uses a fused multiply-add instructions while computing an expression of the format `x + y*z`.

Suppose expressions `a` and `b` have been computed with excess precision and are positive values less than 1 in that excess precision. E.g., for illustration, suppose `double` were implemented with four decimal digits but `a` and `b` were computed with `long double` with six decimal digits. `a` and `b` could both be .999999. Then `a*b` is .999998000001 before rounding, .999998 after rounding to six digits. Now suppose that at this point in the computation, the compiler converts from `long double` to `double`, perhaps because it decides to store this intermediate value on the stack temporarily while it computes some other things from nearby expressions. Converting it to four-digit `double` produces 1.000, because that is the four-decimal-digit number nearest .999998. When the compiler later loads this from the stack and continues evaluation, we have `1 - 1.000`, and the result is zero.

On the other hand, if `a` and `b` are variables, I expect your expression is safe. When a value is assigned to a variable or is converted with a cast operation, the C++ standard requires it to be converted to the nominal type; the result must be a value in the nominal type, without any “extra precision.” Then, given 0 < `a` < 1 and 0 < `b` < 1, the mathematical value (that, without floating-point rounding) `a`•`b` is less than `a` and is less than `b`. Then rounding of `a`•`b` to the nominal type cannot produce a value greater than `a` or `b` with any IEEE-754 rounding method, so it cannot produce 1. (The only requirement here is that the rounding method never skip over values—it might be constrained to round in a particular direction, upward or downward or toward zero or whatever, but it never goes past a representable value in that direction to get to a value farther away from the unrounded result. Since we know `a`•`b` is bounded above by both `a` and `b`, rounding cannot produce any result greater than the lesser of `a` and `b`.)

Formally, the C++ standard does not impose any requirements on the accuracy of floating-point results. So a C++ implementation could use a bonkers rounding mode that produced 3.14 for .9*.9. Aside from implementations flushing subnormals to zero, I am not aware of any C++ implementations that do not obey the requirement above. Flushing subnormals to zero will not affect calculations in `1 - a*b` when `a` and `b` are near 1. (In a perverse floating-point format, with an exponent range narrower than the significand and no subnormal values, .9999 could be representable while .0001 is not because the exponent required for it is out of range. Then `1-.9999*.9999`, which would produce .0002 in normal four-digit arithmetic, would produce 0 due to underflow. No such formats are in normal hardware.)

So, if `a` and `b` are variables, 0 < `a` < 1 and 0 < `b` < 1, and your C++ implementation is reasonable (may use extra precision, may flush subnormals, does not use perverse floating-point formats or rounding), then `1 - a*b` does not evaluate to zero.

Comment: Answer accepted.  Your answer provides an example of the bad behavior using a (sadly) pretty main stream floating point system.  I hate long double.... and thank you for pointing out how they can mess up my expressions!

Answer (score 0):

There is a mathematical proof that it will never be >= 1.  I don't have it handy.... you may want to ask on the math stack overflow site if you are interested in studying the proof. But your instincts are correct.  It will never be >= 1.

Now, we must be careful because floating point arithmetic is only an approximation of math and has limitations.  I'm not an expert on these limitations, but the floating-point standard is very carefully designed and provides certain guarantees. I'm pretty sure one of them includes (or implies) that x * y where x < 1 and y < 1 is guaranteed to be < 1.

Comment: *'I'm pretty sure'* would be of quite some value if you were member of IEEE or C++ standards committee...

Comment: @Aconcagua, anyone can read the standard.  The committee holds no secret information.  "I'm pretty sure" implies that I have not recently read it nor memorized it, but I remember the gist of it.  It goes to great lengths to avoid non-intuitive results and provides particular guarantees to advance that goal.

Comment: What use is an answer based in vague memories?

Comment: Re “There is a mathematical proof that it will never be >= 1”: By definition of `<`, a < 1 means a+j = 1 for some positive number j. And b+k = 1 for some positive k. Then (a+j)•(b+k) = 1•1 ⇒ ab+ak+bj+jk = 1 ⇒ ab+(ak+bj+jk) = 1. Since a and k are positive, ak is positive (property of multiplication). Similarly, bk and jk are positive. So ak+bj+jk is positive (property of addition). Letting m = ak+bj+jk, we have ab+m = 1, where m is a positive number, so ab < 1.

Comment: However, that is insufficient for reasoning that `a*b` < 1 in floating-point arithmetic, as it is necessary to prove that `a`•`b` does not round to 1.

Answer (score -1):

You can check that even if using the highest float or double that is lower than 1, and multiplying by itself, the result will be lower than 1. Any multiplication of numbers lower than that must give a smaller result.

Here is the code I ran, with the results in comments:

```
float a = nextafterf(1, 0); // 0.999999940
double b = nextafter(1, 0); // 0.99999999999999989
float c = a * a; // 0.999999881
double d = b * b; // 0.99999999999999978
```

Comment: This only shows it working for one specific implementation of floating point.

Comment: @MarkRansom, there are very few implementations out there.  Virtually everything follows the IEEE floating point standard.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was showing an example. OP can run similar code on his compiler and verify the result

Comment: @JoelFan granted 99.99% of implementations will use [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) but the C++ standard doesn't mandate it because it wants to be inclusive.  I could easily imagine a small embedded processor that uses a math library that differs slightly.

Comment: @EyalK. if the math is implemented via a library you could easily get a different result between two successive versions of a compiler.

Comment: @MarkRansom, only in theory.  In practice they all follow the IEEE standard for floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: I put an edit on for clarity.  I'm not assuming IEEE 754 compliance.

Comment: @CortAmmon, (a) you should definitely assume IEEE 754 compliance, because every C++ implementation follows it, in practice. (b) if you insist that you can't assume the standard, then your question is unanswerable and should be closed.

Comment: @JoelFan in this context "standard" has a very specific meaning, it's about the C++ standard not the IEEE standard.  You need to be careful with your wording lest people get the wrong impression.

Comment: @MarkRansom, as others have already said, the C++ standard provides no guarantees to follow any particular floating point standard.  In practice, (nearly?) all of them follow IEEE 754

Comment: Independent of IEEE 754 compliance, this only shows the result for the default rounding mode, and the question clearly states that every rounding mode is of concern. FWIW, it still works, but setting the rounding mode to FE_UPWARD does change the result of the multiplication to the next largest value, which is `nextafter(1.0, 0.0)`. (Default rounding gives you `nextafter(nextafter(1.0, 0.0), 0.0)`.) `%a` formatting is highly recommended for this experiment.

Comment: @CortAmmon Can you guarantee your case 100%? No. But you can be sure that in 99% of cases your code will work, and you can test it specifically for the compiler you are working on. As for the CPU not complying, I can only see that in an embedded system, and there you will have to test your specific case anyways

Comment: This only shows it working for one specific pair of floating point numbers. It doesn't prove the general point. Only mathematical reason or an appeal to a normative reference can do that.

Comment: @user207421, no, only a floating-point standard can do that, by providing well-defined guarantees that cover whole classes of examples.  The IEEE 754 does just that, by providing certain guarantees, in the form of "if a is such-and-such and b is such-and-such, you can rely on a * b being such-and-such".  I believe the standard guarantees the behavior he is asking about, and every generally-available C++ compiler implements the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: @JoelFan: “… every generally-available C++ compiler implements the IEEE 754 standard”: No, they do not. The “generally-available” compilers I am familiar with **use** IEEE-754 arithmetic, but that is not the same as implementing the standard, if implementing it means conforming to it. A compiler generally cannot even implement the standard by itself; it has to rely on the operating system to set appropriate modes, subnormal behaviors, and so on.

Comment: @JoelFan: Compilers deviate from the IEEE 754 standard in various ways. For example, the C++ standard allows expressions to be evaluated with more precision than their nominal type. With IEEE 754,  given `double` variables `c` = `b` and `d = a`, `a*b−c*d` ought to evaluate to zero, but it might not because (using `t0` to indicate a temporary intermediate result) `t0 = a*b` might be calculated first and rounded to `double` but then evaluate `t0−c*d` in a single fused multiply-add that does not round `c*d` before doing the subtraction.